# error on show all date items from datebase

Tags: php, sql, mysql

error on show all date items from datebase:

**on datebase:**

```
Title1
Title2
Title3
```

**php code:**

```
$postdb = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wtable");
$post = mysql_fetch_assoc($postdb);

while ($poste = @mysql_fetch_array($postdb))
  {
  echo $poste['posttitle'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

**output:**

```
Title2
Title3
```

Comment: Comment this line `//$post = mysql_fetch_assoc($postdb);`
Because you already fetched first row but did not echoed

Comment: +Shakti, and get rid of that ugly evil @ operator.

Comment: please write true code and thx

Comment: @ is bad, because it suppresses errors. When something fails, you have to take care of it accordingly. @ just means that you will ignore the errors that may occur, and it makes debugging hard, because these errors are not show (in development environment, ofcourse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$post = mysql_fetch_assoc($postdb);
```

Is returning the first result and then moving the cursor forward.

Comment out this line and try again.

Example:

```
$postdb = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wtable");
//$post = mysql_fetch_assoc($postdb); <-- comment out this line

while ($poste = mysql_fetch_array($postdb)) { // <-- don't use @ here, we want to know if something went wrong!
  echo $poste['posttitle'];
  echo "<br />";
}
```